# Elysia cron and feeds being stuck - how to resume the imports?

Tags: 7, feeds, cron

I have a bunch of [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) imports, programmed automatically with [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron).

There is a problem with the size of the content to be loaded, as the import uses to hang, and always at about the same approx. point in a definite feed. The feed, imported manually, throws no errors and do all its stuff perfectly, only fails in automated cron, getting stuck.

After I unblock the Feed with this

```
 update feeds_source set state = 'b:0;';
 update feeds_source set fetcher_result='b:0;';
```

And reset the Elysia table with this

```
 UPDATE elysia_cron SET running = 0 WHERE name = :name_of_process
```

sometimes the Elysia Cron starts again, but, to my dismay, no Feed process is launched even if Elysia Cron says otherwise. There is a Running indication, but no feed importation is done, and the progress indicator in the Feed itself indicates that it is not working.

What can I do, someone has the same problems? I have read tons of documentation, but I find no solution, I see terrible stories on the net about updating processes enduring for weeks, shouldn't just 4.000 products (nodes, taxonomies) load in just 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the following lines had been wiped out from the code somehow in my module:

```
 while (FEEDS_BATCH_COMPLETE != $source->import()){
// nothing
 } // while
```

This piece of code keeps de feeds working after it finishes. When the resetting is done via phpMyAdmin, the cron itself (called every minute) launches again the tasks. The Elysia task when being called, but the callback did not do anything as the feed had started and the code lacked the while() construction